# File not saved on different computer using outputstream and filechooser

Tags: java, apache-poi, jfilechooser

I am trying to edit inside a .xls file using Apache poi library. All the updation is succesfull on local computer.But, i am stuck when jar file of application does not saved excel file on computer on which it is installed.

```
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.setTitle("Generated data of Dvat ");
            fileChooser.setTitle("Generate XLS File of " + "Dvat 31");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                    new ExtensionFilter("XLS Files", "*.xls"));
            fileChooser.setInitialFileName(Common
                    .replaceWhiteSpaceAndSlash("Dvat31")
                    + "_"
                    + Common.replaceWhiteSpaceAndSlash(Common.comp.getName()+"_")
                    +this.fromdate+"_"+this.todate+ ".xls");
            fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(System
                    .getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop"));

            File selectedFileName = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(selectedFileName!=null)
            {
            String fileName=absolutePath;
            HSSFWorkbook wb = HSSFReadWrite.readFile(fileName);
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(selectedFileName.getAbsolutePath());

      // Updation On .xls Sheet.
                    row = sheet.getRow(34);
                for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
                {
                    if(i==4)
                    {
                        cell=row.getCell(i);
                        cell.setCellValue(this.consignmentTotal);

                    }
                }
       // Closing workbook and outputstream.
      wb.write(stream);
            stream.close();
            wb.close();
```

Comment: 2 Questions , both local and installed systems are running on windows? what is the value of `absolutePath` ?

Comment: Try it with `new FileOutputStream(selectedFileName);` No need to do anything to the `File` returned by the chooser.

Comment: I m using ubntu. It works fine on mine computer , while on the target computer FileDialogs opens but unable to save file on hardDrive.

Comment: @Pritam Tiwari: Any errormessages? Or does everything work as expected and the file is just not saved, i.e. does not appear where it should be?

Comment: @Frank i haven't got any error messages however. Every time file save dialog appear on screen but unable to save file.

Comment: @Pritam Tiwari: Difficult to say what is wrong as the code example is not complete, perhaps some lines are missing that could indicate more. Why do you use HSSFReadWrite? It is a "File for HSSF testing/examples" as the comment states. Open your workbook like this `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(fileName));`

Comment: In order to create new .xls file , it might lost micros and all other hidden formulas.That's why i used older one .xls and trying to edit inside the file.One another question i would like ask ? i am accessing file from /opt/application/vat/form_data_31.xls . It works fine in mine computer , but shows file not found exception on different computer.